# Is there a way to enlarge the zmq small message limitation?

Tags: limit, message, publish-subscribe, zeromq

I understand that the small message size limit is predefined as 30 in the source code (C++) . but when I change it to let say 512, it parsed out fine. however when I tried to send it, it did not show up on the wire by looking at it using wireshark ( data length = 0 )

Any suggestions for me? My messages are pretty much between 100 to 200, if i cannot change it, How can i send my message via pub-sub pattern?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you care at all? The small message limit is completely transparent to the user.

Comment: Exactly. You shouldn't change the source as it is optimized for performance. Different message sizes are handled differently so you shouldn't be messing with it. Just send your messages normally. Zeromq will split and join them after if needed.